# Display Map v2 in popup Window not display in android?

Tags: android, popup, google-maps-android-api-2

i want to open the popup window on that i used the map v2 for displaying map v2 in popup window but is not display
here i put my xml layout and activity class

[image]

> main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> popupstellodetailpage.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popuplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoncancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             />

          <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/popupmapview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



</LinearLayout>
```

> MapActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity {


     PopupWindow pw;
     GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                initiatePopupWindow();
            }
        });

    }


    private void initiatePopupWindow() 
    {
        try 
        {

            //We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater, use the context of this activity
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupstellodetailpage,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popuplayout));

            // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
            pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);

            // display the popup in the center
            pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


            map= ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                     .findFragmentById(R.id.popupmapview)).getMap(); 


            Button buttoncancel=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.buttoncancel);
            buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     pw.dismiss();
                }

            });

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may Helps you [Check Here](https://docs.google.com/a/viitorcloud.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw)  check here all Your Require possibility  to show map is Full Fill or not IN `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<permission
        android:name="your.Activity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.Activity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />

<meta-data    
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"    
   android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

Comment: every thing is right but problem is is not display in popup but is display in if i direct use in main class

Comment: check in your mainClass if not getting tell  me will try to help yo

Answer (score 0):

their is only two silly problem as I found .. You just change this fragment

```
                <fragment
                android:id="@+id/popupmapview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

to this..

```
                <fragment
                android:id="@+id/popupmapview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

and change a line in method [initiatePopupWindow]

```
map= ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.popupmapview)).getMap();
```

to this..

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.popupmapview)).getMap();
```